# Fastest way to fetch huge records using ActiveRecords and Rails (find_each is slow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have a tables with more than 500k records, and I'm fetching the data at the moment this way :

```
  Account.find_each(:conditions =>{:status =>STATUS[:waiting]}) do |user|    
    unless user.games.include? game
      begin
        user.account_games.create!(:game_id => game.id,:status  => STATUS[:waiting])
        user.activate            
      rescue Exception => e
        $LOG.error "Error : #{e.to_s}"
      end          
    end
  end
```

Now i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but one thing for sure, this is very slow, I don't know if it's the find_each or anything else, but would highly appreciate it if you can give me any hint to make this faster.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you identify which part of your code is slow and also had a look at the generated sqls ?

Comment: How many rows match the desired status? Do you have any indexes? Why not push the `user.games.include? game` filter down into the database?

Comment: +1 for @muistooshort -- the fastest way to use the database is to _use_ the database, not to apply filters in the app layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things happening:

First is a select query-

```
 @account = Account.where(:status =>STATUS[:waiting])
```

Second is Create on each-

```
@account.each do |user|

 unless user.games.include? game
      begin
        user.account_games.create!(:game_id => game.id,:status  => STATUS[:waiting])
        user.activate            
      rescue Exception => e
        $LOG.error "Error : #{e.to_s}"
      end          
    end  
  end
```

UPDATE:

There is a noted [Rails Performance Tip: Query Optimization](http://tenmiles.com/blog/2011/07/rails-performance-tip-query-optimization/) by `Anand`.

Also check [QueryReviewer gem](https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer).

Apart from that there are many factors that can speed up the performance like some
that are in the post [Active Record Query Interface Optimization](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/80-active-record-query-interface-optimization).

Comment: but don't u think this will eat so much memory and effect the system ? specially if i have so much data ? like 500k or even 1 million records ?

Comment: thanks a lot for the help here, very helpful, anyways few notes, not sure if i can use the gym, since at this processes, it is like a worker processes rather than a Rails one, about Eager loading , I will check it out

Comment: btw one more question, why do u think adding index to :status, :game_id could help ? i mean no selecting here, just inserting u know

Comment: I appreciate ur help here, anyways i'm confused here :) let me make it simpler , I have the following tables Account, Game, AccountGame, as you notice, AccountGame is for has_many :through one. in this case how can I optimise it ? plus, as for indexing, is it related ? i mean I'm not selecting rather than inserting data, please advice \

Comment: You are using the two queries. The first one is to get the account with the status and the second one is the create one. It would be better for the first one, because it is the select query and it accelerates the search in sorting in this column. And Foreign keys are something searched for a lot.

Comment: thanks a lot Saurab, make very sense, as for another issue, u recommend using .where instead of find_each for big data ?

Comment: My main question here, as long u seems to have the experience with that, in my case ( huge number of data ) is it better to use .where or .find_each ? what would u use if u were in my case ? performance matters in my case, but not over stability

Comment: NO..I haven't recommended to use .where for big data. It is just for your understanding that first you are selecting and then you are creating. For big data always use find_each. Check http://www.icyte.com/system/snapshots/fs1/4/7/4/3/4743e27706c94332b4fc807aa7424b17085ca79f/index.html

Comment: the link is empty somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

Use find_by_sql clause with your model.

Comment: You can use eager loading of all records by using include keyword with find.

Answer (score 0):

I think of 2 options:

1) Select all in Active Record then use ruby to iterate,  Will require a lot of memory.

2) Write the query in sql and put it in a stored procedure and call that procedure.